# Java heap utilization in spark job

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I am running a Spark Streaming job through Java. I have a 4 node cluster on AWS with cloudera distribution, out of which 3 are compute nodes. I need to record how much java heap is utilized on each executor/node of cluster when my job runs. I am using the method of getRunTime() but i am getting a value which i believe is from driver execution.

Is there a method i can use to capture individual heap utilization ?

Answer (score 3):

Spark exposes such metrics through [Sinks](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html). Once of them is JMX counters, but you can choose other formats (CSV, Console, Graphite, Ganglia, Slf4j). This requires you to add a `metrics.properties` file on the worker nodes. Here is an example of JMX counters:

```
*.sink.jmx.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.JmxSink

master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

And then, it exposes many metrics, some of them which are:

```
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.heap.committed
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.heap.init
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.heap.max
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.heap.usage
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.heap.used
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.non-heap.committed
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.non-heap.init
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.non-heap.max
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.non-heap.usage
{SparkAppId}.{ExecutorId}.jvm.non-heap.used
```

And that way you can monitor your applications heap use.